# How do i change the look and feel of my application?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, look-and-feel

I had an application which was using the 'Windows' look and feel, i refactored something and ended up breaking a lot of classes, i did an undo and run the application to see if it was running ok. This is where i realised that it is using the 'metal' look and feel.

I already tried adding the code to all the classes to change all the look and feel of GUI but to no avail

Code which was there before after the refractor

```
if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
```

The code i added to try and fix the issue

```
if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
```

Overall, i want the application GUI to have the windows look and feel, Any ideas what could be causing this issue.

Thanks in advance Everyone

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

[for more details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

UPDATE

---

also try with this

```
import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel;

javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new WindowsLookAndFeel());
```

Comment: Where about would i put this code. I am a little confused, am i removing the code i posted and replacing it with this or just adding this code.

Comment: if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;

                }

Comment: Changing this didnt seem to fix the problem, I am using the windows look and feel for the netbeans IDE. This is where is pulls the look and feel from isnt it ?

Comment: try this link https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel